# aws s3 bucket policy without public access

Tags: amazon-s3, swagger-ui, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am hosting few api containers in aws ecs. one of the api (api.example.com) needs to upload images to the aws s3 bucket. Now the developers are using swagger after authenticating it via some token (not sure what they are exactly doing)

I have created a bucket policy but image uploading only works when the "Principal" is set to "*" .     when we use " * " at "Principal" the bucket is open to any aws account and the aws is showing a warning message. 
is there any way we can make the bucket more secure? at the same time it is able to upload images via api.example.com through browser.

My bucket policy is pasted below

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "xxxxx",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "xxxxx",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucket/*"
    }
]
```

Comment: How is your application on ECS calling Amazon S3? Is it using an SDK? From where is it getting AWS credentials?

Comment: What are other options did you try other than * for Principal? Did you try giving access to task role (using its arn) and granting access to the assumed role? What error did you get when you tried with something other than * for Principal?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeh the developers are using php sdk, I have made the bucket private again.  They are now able to upload it via aws "access_key_id" and "secret_access_key" and the region in the aws sdk.   I am now using the cloudfront as the "Principal" in bucket policy so that images can be served only from the cloudfront custom domain name.   Can we attach an inline policy to "ecsInstanceRole" with amazon bucket access so that we can avoid hard coding the aws credentials in the adk? Early I used this method for connecting to dynamod tables and was working fine.

Comment: If you are using a role with ECS, then credentials will be automatically provided to the apps running on ECS. Yes, give that role permissions to access S3 (as shown in your policy above). A policy on a role does not require a `Principal`.